# change span text using jquery based on parent element class

Tags: jquery, html

I checked through the forum but didn't find the solution for my problem. I am adding a class on an element based on the img src value. If img src contains 'amazon' a class is added to closest li element and based on that li element i'm changing text of a span. Till here everything is fine, after this I want to change the text of span whose parent li element doesn't have that class name. I can't figure out the solution for it. Here is my code.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var select = 'img[src*="images-amazon.com"]';  
    jQuery(select).closest("li").addClass("sac-amazon");  

    var cls = jQuery("li.sac-amazon");
    var currency = jQuery("span.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol");

    if(cls){
        currency.text("US $");
    }else if(!cls){
        currency.text("SG $");
    }   

});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to use `hasClass()`. You need to check `if(cls.hasClass('CLASSNAME') {  } `

Comment: @MilanChheda...thanx for the reply. I already tried it but didn't get what I was looking for. satpal's solution worked for me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I want to change the text of span whose parent li element doesn't have that class name*

You need to target the child span only. use [`:not()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) to target `li` not having the class then use [descendant selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
jQuery("li.sac-amazon span.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol").text("US $");
jQuery("li:not(.sac-amazon) span.woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol").text("SG $");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (replace 'New Text' with the string of your choice):

```
jQuery('ul li').each(function(){
  var t = jQuery(this);
  if(!t.hasClass('sac-amazon')){
    t.text('New text');
  }
});
```

Comment: @nimsrules...thanx for the reply...satpal's solution workd for me. thanx once again